# Do we need preposition "in" or "for" in a Present Perfect sentence?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage

Is "I haven't seen him **in** months" a correct English phrase?
And if it is, what's the difference (if there's any) between that and "I haven't seen him **for** months"?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137845/using-in-in-present-perfect-tense

Answer (score 2):

- I haven't seen him for months
- I haven't seen him in months

The two sentences are equivalent as they are written here. However, the first sentence can be changed in a way that the second cannot:

- Whenever he finds a new hobby, I don't see him for months at a time. (**good**)
- Whenever he finds a new hobby, I don't see him in months at a time. (**bad**)

"For months" can mean any period of time that spans several months, *regardless of when it takes place*.
When you say "in months", you mean a period of time that is **currently ongoing** (or it abruptly stopped just now)

---

But your question's title asks a different question:

> Do we need preposition “in” or “for” in a Present Perfect sentence?

No. A present perfect tense does not require "in" or "for". It very much depends on the words you are using.

- I haven't killed anyone.
- I have chopped down the cherry tree.
- Have I answered your question?

All of these are present perfect tense, but they do not need "in" or "for".